# Como posso ler um ficheiro CSV com diferentes tipos de linha?

Tags: c, struct, lista

Estou a tentar ler um ficheiro CSV que tem linhas diferentes. estou a usar fgets e strtok para guardar numa lista. o problema é que sendo linhas diferentes não sei como parar e passar para a seguinte.

```
typedef struct{
int id_viagem;
int duracao;
int mes_init;
int dia_init;
int ano_init;
int hora_init;
int min_init;
int id_estacao_init;
int mes_final;
int dia_final;
int ano_final;
int min_final;
int id_estacao_final;
char *bicicleta;
int tipo; 
int nascimento;
char *genero;
}INFO_VIAGEM;
```

Esta é a estrutura que origina a lista, e estes são os diferentes tipos de linha:

41,460,7/28/2011 12:10:00,22,7/28/2011 12:18:00,49,B00353,Registered,1972,Male

61,1315,7/28/2011 12:33:00,36,7/28/2011 12:55:00,38,B00228,Casual,,

```
auxx=strtok(NULL, str_div);
    tipo=auxx;
    if(strcmp(tipo, "Casual") == 0){
        z.tipo=0;

    }
    else{
        z.tipo=1;
        auxx=strtok(NULL, str_div);
        z.nascimento=atoi(auxx);

        auxx=strtok(NULL, str_div3);
        z.genero=auxx;
    }
```

Assim como a primeira linha e sempre registered ele lê sempre mesmo o que não há. Como posso fazer?

Comment: Edite e faça a pergunta em português ou utilize o stackoverflow em inglês.

Comment: obrigado, não tinha dado conta da diferença do site. Esta já editada.